# i want to use mdf hashes reverse function in my website

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, md5

i use this website http://md5.gromweb.com/ to decrypt md5 hashes password from my database and i want to do same functionality on my web site for learning purposes not hacking or anything else. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Easy enough: start building a database of values=>hashes, and write a small interface script to query the database, neither is particularly difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashes cannot be "decrypted". The only way to get a plaintext value that corresponds to a hash value is by trying all possible plaintext values and see which results in the same hash. The website you link to simply has a giant database of such value → hash mappings. Nothing more, nothing less.